# How to properly smooth edge

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edges, bevel

What is a proper way to make edge (marked with marker) seamless in a situation below. I can't bevel it, also bevel modifier does nothing. Tried cutting it and bridging it back together. Removed doubles, recalculated normals... Running out of ideas... I could theoretically make one big face, but once converted to triangles in game engine it looks broken.

EDIT: So as requested more informations. I am modeling a 3d model of a glider plane. I need to create a seamless transition of object 2 on object 1(Old pictures were cutout of that section). Basicly i must smooth out edge marked with yellow color (all around the profile) so it would be like one part with fuselage. One the picture below is a look from a real plane i am trying to achieve.

File:
[image]


[image: Markings of objects]

[image: Closeup of object 2]

[image: Real bevel from fuselage to wing root]

Comment: sorry it's not clear what you're trying to do, what shape are you trying to create exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as your demand has changed, here is a proposition for your plane wing, tell me if it's ok:

[image]

Comment: Result is what i want, but i have two parts: horizontal and vertical which i combined in object on all the pictures (hope that makes sense). So when i select edge marked on first picture it doesnt allow me to bevel it.

Comment: "which i combined in object" -> what do you mean, please give more details about your project, the object or animation you're trying to create

Comment: is it possible to send you a mail or something and i can give you details or even share .blend file, so there wont be so many random pictures in post here?

Comment: it's better if you edit your message and give more details, as many as you can, is it for an animation, are there two different objects? 2 different meshes in 1 object? etc...

Comment: I have hopefuly added more useful informations...

Comment: so they are separate from the main body of the plane, and they should follow its profile along the black lines you've drawn? In that case you should use the body, cut with a knife, and join with the wings, something like that... could you share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yes I would like to join object 1 to object 2, so it would like like one object

Comment: oh ok so one unique object (body + wings welded) and not 2 separate objects? I will check your file tomorrow   ;)

Comment: Yes, one object but seamless (like beveled) edge. Thank you!

Comment: Ok, I've edited, tell me if you understand and if it answers

Comment: I've edited, you can skip the bevel and work on the wing shape afterwards, it may be simpler  ;)

Answer (score 1):

One subdiv. approach would be to model the entire fuselage and wings as one piece.

Model under a mirror modifier, and your final expected level of subdivision, using as few loops as possible to capture the curvatures of your reference. The wing is then just an extrusion of some vertices you have <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> slid into the right profile.

Introduce a loop along the line of your cut, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > Edge Data mark it as creased, with a weight of 1.

Retain an intact copy of the model.

<kbd>V</kbd> Rip the edges marking the cut,  separate the pieces. <kbd>F</kbd> fill and <kbd>I</kbd> inset the holes. The inset at the acute angle of the trailing edge may need repairing by hand, merging overlapping vertices.

You can  delete the inner nGons, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > Grid Fill them, if there are an even number of vertices.

[image]

[image]

Holding loops cut close to the creased edges should preserve the previous curvatures very close to the cut.

This can be the result:

[image]

If you wanted to make the join completely invisible from a normals point of view, you could use the intact model and a Data Transfer modifier to copy the normals from it to a vertex group of the cut copy.. but it would be a lot of fiddling.. for most uses you would 'magic' the cut away, substituting the intact model.